# How to copy and paste a full row data from sqlite in iOS?

Tags: ios, sqlite, copy-paste

I want to copy and paste the table data from 1 id to another id in sqlite. I am using sqlite with iOS. I have a category X with id 1 and other one is Y with id 2. X has n level data in tree and i want to copy the whole tree of X and paste for Y with id 2.

How is it possible in iOS?

Comment: So row data or *raw* data? Not even close to each other.

Comment: In this case, you can `SELECT` from the one database and `INSERT` it into the other one.